# Complex pivoting/looping to wrangle data

Tags: r, tidyr, data-wrangling

I have data on relatedness between individuals in a dataset, where each individual is related to between 0 and 5 others. The data is currently in a sort-of wide format, such that each individual represents one row, with separate columns for 'RP' (a unique number assigned to a pair of relatives) and 'Factor' (a coefficient representing relatedness degree, specific for a given pairing). For example, in the reprex here, person 1 is related to person 2 to a degree of .09, with 876 being the unique number representing their relationship.

I need the data to be in a different format, such that there is a row **per pairing**, with a column for the ID of the first individual of that pairing, a column for the second individual, and a column for the relatedness coefficient. For combinations of IDs where there is no relationship, no row is required.

I have tried a variety of ways to achieve this transformation (involving a series of pivots), but can't get there. Perhaps a loop is required?
Would love any advice!

Current data:

```
ID<-c(1,2,3,4)
RP_1<-c(876,876,032,NA_real_)
RP_2<-c(NA_real_,032,NA_real_,NA_real_)
RP_3<-c(NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_)
RP_4<-c(NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_)
RP_5<-c(NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_,NA_real_)
Factor_1<-c(.09,.09,.1,NA_integer_)
Factor_2<-c(NA_integer_,.1,NA_integer_,NA_integer_)
Factor_3<-c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_)
Factor_4<-c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_)
Factor_5<-c(NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_,NA_integer_)

df<-data.frame(ID, RP_1,RP_2,RP_3,RP_4,RP_5, Factor_1,Factor_2,Factor_3,Factor_4,Factor_5)

print(df)
    ID RP_1 RP_2 RP_3 RP_4 RP_5 Factor_1 Factor_2 Factor_3 Factor_4 Factor_5
1  1  876   NA   NA   NA   NA     0.09       NA       NA       NA       NA
2  2  876   32   NA   NA   NA     0.09      0.1       NA       NA       NA
3  3   32   NA   NA   NA   NA     0.10       NA       NA       NA       NA
4  4   NA   NA   NA   NA   NA       NA       NA       NA       NA       NA
```

Desired format:

```
ID1<-c(1,2)
ID2<-c(2,3)
Coefficient<-c(.09,.1)
df2<-data.frame(ID1,ID2,Coefficient)

print(df2)
  ID1 ID2 Coefficient
1   1   2        0.09
2   2   3        0.10
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You’ll need to pivot everything except `ID` longer, then compute `ID1` and `ID2` labels within each `RP`, then pivot `ID` wider.

```
library(tidyr)
library(dplyr) # >= v1.1.0

df %>%
  pivot_longer(
    !ID, 
    names_to = c(".value", NA), 
    names_sep = "_", 
    values_drop_na = TRUE
  ) %>%
  mutate(pair_no = paste0("ID", row_number()), .by = RP) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = pair_no, values_from = ID) %>%
  select(ID1, ID2, Coefficient = Factor)
```

```
# A tibble: 2 × 3
    ID1   ID2 Coefficient
  <dbl> <dbl>       <dbl>
1     1     2        0.09
2     2     3        0.1
```

Note you’ll need the latest version of dplyr to use the `.by` argument; otherwise you can use `group_by(RP)`.

Comment: Ahh fantastic, what an elegant solution! Thanks so much zephryl :)